# Get maximum from struct with select on all fields Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a field of type ArrayType[Struct] in my Spark dataframe. The structure of this field looks like this:

```
 |-- categories: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- categoryId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- confidence: float (nullable = true)
 |-- count: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- naming: integer (nullable = true)
```

And there are multiple categories with confidences in the source data:

```
categoryId1| categoryConfidence1| categoryId2| categoryConfidence2| categoryId3| categoryConfidence3
1| 0.34| 2| 0.57| 3| 0.89
```

I would like to filter out categories and confidence to get only maximum confidence which should look like this:

```
categoryId3| categoryConfidence3
3| 0.89
```

Except for these fields, I would like to keep all the other in dataframe. Final expected result would be:

```
 |-- categories: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- categoryId: integer (nullable = true) //corresponding to max confidence value
 |    |    |-- confidence: float (nullable = true) //only max confidence
 |-- count: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- naming: integer (nullable = true)
```

My current solution creates an additional confidence column which is not something I need:

```
  val categoriesWindow = Window.partitionBy("categories.categoryId", "categories.confidence")
    val res = df.map(_
      .withColumn("category", explode($"categories"))
      .withColumn("confidence", max($"category.confidence").over(categoriesWindow))
      .drop("categories"))
```

What can I do to improve this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Spark 2.4 and using the higher-order functions.

```
val df = Seq((10,"abc")).toDF("count","naming")

val df2 = df.withColumn("categories",expr(""" array(named_struct('categoryId',1,'confidence',0.34),
                                 named_struct('categoryId',2,'confidence',0.57),
                                 named_struct('categoryId',3,'confidence',0.89)
                          ) """)).select("categories","count","naming")
df2.printSchema

root
 |-- categories: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- categoryId: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- confidence: decimal(2,2) (nullable = false)
 |-- count: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- naming: string (nullable = true)

df2.show(false)

+---------------------------------+-----+------+
|categories                       |count|naming|
+---------------------------------+-----+------+
|[[1, 0.34], [2, 0.57], [3, 0.89]]|10   |abc   |
+---------------------------------+-----+------+

val df3 = df2.withColumn("x_max", expr("""array_max(categories.categoryId) """))

df3.createOrReplaceTempView("cassie")

df3.show(false)

+---------------------------------+-----+------+-----+
|categories                       |count|naming|x_max|
+---------------------------------+-----+------+-----+
|[[1, 0.34], [2, 0.57], [3, 0.89]]|10   |abc   |3    |
+---------------------------------+-----+------+-----+

spark.sql(""" select filter(categories, a -> a.categoryid=x_max ) category, count, naming  from cassie """).show(false)

+-----------+-----+------+
|category   |count|naming|
+-----------+-----+------+
|[[3, 0.89]]|10   |abc   |
+-----------+-----+------+
```

Update-1:

If you don't need views, then you can use below.

```
df2.withColumn("x_max", expr("""array_max(categories.confidence) """))
   .withColumn("categories2", expr(""" filter(categories, a -> a.confidence=x_max ) """) )
   .show

+--------------------+-----+------+-----+-----------+
|          categories|count|naming|x_max|categories2|
+--------------------+-----+------+-----+-----------+
|[[1, 0.34], [2, 0...|   10|   abc| 0.89|[[3, 0.89]]|
+--------------------+-----+------+-----+-----------+
```

Update-2

```
df2.withColumn("x_max", expr("""array_max(categories.confidence) """).cast("double")).printSchema

root
 |-- categories: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- categoryId: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- confidence: decimal(2,2) (nullable = false)
 |-- count: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- naming: string (nullable = true)
 |-- x_max: double (nullable = true
```

Comment: It's is a good solution but array_max should be counted on confidence instead of id. Also, I would not want to use sql queries for transformations

Comment: OK - I updated to use the confidence and without the views.

Comment: Thanks. I meant also expr usages as they are not type safe. For instance, I'd change max calculation to `withColumn("x_max", array_max($"categories.confidence"))`
However, I am not sure how to change filter transformation to similar form.

Comment: I meant changing `withColumn("categories2", expr(""" filter(categories, a -> a.confidence=x_max ) """) )` to use functions like filter instead of sql expr

Comment: Higher order functions doesn't have equivalent dataframe operations. So you can use with sql expressions. Once you have narrowed down, you should be good to use it. This will perform better than udfs. Give it a try.

Comment: Is there a way not to use higher-order functions in this case and use dataframe operations instead?

Answer (score 0):

Giving a dataframe like:

```
+--------------------+-----+------+
|          categories|count|naming|
+--------------------+-----+------+
|[[1, 0.5], [2, 0.6]]|    5|     1|
+--------------------+-----+------+
```

Using an udf can help a lot in these cases. Maybe it an be done with the array functions included in the 2.4 version, although dealing with struct types with this functions can be a little bit tricky. Create a new type like:

```
case class CategConfidence(categoryId: Int, confidence: Float)
```

Spark will transform the output of the udf of an ***Array[CategConfidence]*** to

```
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- categoryId: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- confidence: float (nullable = false)
```

With the udf you can handle the Array using plain Scala:

```
val udf_getmax = udf {array: Seq[Row] =>
  val tupleArr = array.map(row => (row.getAs[Int]("categoryId"), row.getAs[Float]("confidence")))
  Array(tupleArr.map { case (a,b) => CategConfidence(a,b) }.sortBy(-_.confidence).head)
}
```

then drop the categories column  and you obtain:

```
val fd1 = df.withColumn("max_confidence_categories", udf_getmax(col("categories"))).drop("categories")

+-----+------+-------------------------+
|count|naming|max_confidence_categories|
+-----+------+-------------------------+
|    5|     1|               [[2, 0.6]]|
+-----+------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: I am not sure that sorting each array field for a big dataset would be good in terms or performance

Comment: The memory consumption and GC increase. The solution with UDFs is quite simple, however, if there are problems with memory or performance you can, instead of using case classes, use arrays to represent the CategConfidence as an Array[Float] and then you can use spark sql functions to update the schema from ArrayType(FLoatType) to Struct(List(StructField("categoryId", IntegerType),StructField("confidence", FloatType)) indexing the array.